# ABRecordRef how to link to existing contact programatically?

Tags: xcode, abaddressbook, abrecordref

OK,

maybe I've missed it.  But if I create a new contact thus:

```
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
```

Then set them up with what ever details, what do I call to link this contact to an existing contact, say

```
ABRecordRef exisitingPerson ?
```

Or am I forced to have two records with the same name, which I don't want ?

Comment: Did you got any success in this? Because I am looking for the same thing but no luck yet